# ASP.net Performance and Compile Queries

Tags: asp.net, performance, linq-to-sql

I have an ASP.net site that is essentially just a user interface for a class library I created. Each of the classes in this class library contain a static definition class with static references to compiled queries.

Like so:

```
class MyRecord
{
     /*Some Properties,Fields, and Methods*/

     internal static class Queries
     {
          public static Func<MyDataContext, MyRecord> ACompiledQuery = 
               CompiledQuery.Compile<MyDataContext, MyRecord>(
                    (MyDataContext db) => 
                         from mr in db.MyRecords
                         select mr);
     }
}
```

Given this structure and given that each web page references this library, I have a couple questions

**Question 1:** Every request to an IIS web server essentially starts a new thread, correct?

**Question 2:** If so, does this mean that for every request I end up recompiling these queries?

**Question 3:** Is there anyway to reduce the amount of times I recompile these queries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Static items are shared across threads within the same AppDomain, and so you will no re-compile the query for each request.

Answer (score 0):

Question 1: Every request to an IIS Web server is handled by an existing thread from the application's threadpool

Question 2: Already answered by Joel

Question 3: It is Static so is only either created (or compiled) once when the application is started